# findViewById - in separate class

Tags: java, beginner, android

I'm new to Android and I wanted to create a class that would load an ad inside the current layout.  All the layouts have a `RelativeLayout id=adLayout`

From my main, I have:

```
AdLoader al = new AdLoader();
al.GrabAd(this,"123");
```

Then on my AdLoader.java class I have:

```
public class AdLoader {

    private DfpAdView adView;

    public void GrabAdFor(Activity act, String adId) {
        adView = new DfpAdView(act, AdSize.BANNER, adId);
        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) act.findViewById(R.id.adLayout);
        rl.addView(adView);
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
    }
}
```

Is it incorrect to pass the Activity?  Am I even passing the activity or the View/Context?

Answer (score 1):

You could also make a baseactivity for all the other activity that are going to use the adView

```
    public class BaseActivity extends Activity {

    private DfpAdView adView;
    RelativeLayout rl;
    //some other stuff

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.baseactivity_layout)
        rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.adLayout);
        adView = new DfpAdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, adId);
        rl.addView(adView);
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
    }
}
```

And and make your MainActivity (or all the other activities that are using the adview)

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    }
}
```